# Visual Studio 2012 Secure Publish?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, sftp

Is there an sftp publish method in VS 2012? I only see ftp. 
I may be wrong but I thought VS 2010 had a secure option.

Comment: Have you had a look at the Visual Studio extension site for some SFTP connector plugins? Something like [SFTP Connector](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/979a73c8-4fb6-4515-aded-f4332c08c195) which support VS 2012

Answer (score 0):

The only extension I could find is this one:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/979a73c8-4fb6-4515-aded-f4332c08c195

Oh yeah, same one as you mentioned :)